# How to pass a Form as a function parameter?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function and it looks like this:

```
Function SpawnForm(Form)
    Dim Spawn As New Form With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
    Try
        Spawn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        MainForm.SpawnPanel.Controls.Add(Spawn)
        Spawn.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I want to pass the parameter onto the rest of the function, so if I were to call it as this:

```
SpawnForm(SettingsForm)
```

It will then spawn the existing form in my project called SettingsForm.

I know that the problem is this:

```
Dim Spawn As New Form
```

What should I do differently to pass the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic function with some constraints. This allows you to keep the form creation inside the method (instead of passing an instance). Also return the instance from the function.

```
Private Function SpawnForm(Of T As {New, Form})() As T
    Dim spawn As New T() With {.TopLevel = False, .AutoSize = False}
    Try
        spawn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        MainForm.SpawnPanel.Controls.Add(spawn)
        spawn.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return spawn
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim mySettingsForm = SpawnForm(Of SettingsForm)()
```